# Getting continous loops while trying to view the query executed in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting continous loops while trying to view the query executed in Laravel.

My routes file is as below

```
Route::get('cards','CardsController@index');
Route::get('cards/{id}','CardsController@show');
Route::post('cards/{card}/notes','NotesController@store');
Route::get('notes/{note}/edit','NotesController@edit');
Route::patch('notes/{note}','NotesController@update');
Route::get('/','PagesController@home');
Route::get('/about','PagesController@about');
```

It works perfectly before adding the below code

```
DB::listen(function($sql)
    {
        var_dump($sql);
    });
```

but as soon as I add the above code to my routes file I get continous looping as

[image]

Can any one help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to listen to Query events, you need to edit the `AppServiceProvider`, you can find this information on Laravel docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/database#listening-for-query-events):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        DB::listen(function ($query) {
            var_dump($query);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot identify the error, it's not clear. I see a dump for Query object.